# Laravel 5.1 Modular structure create two type of login

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1

In Laravel 5.1 Multiple Modular structure using
https://github.com/Artem-Schander/L5Modular
Need to create two type of login one for backend admin login and one for front user using different table how can achieve that. 
I have made two login system. a) for Users and b) for Administrator
I have made two tables  a) for Users and b) for Administrator

Comment: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query Getting below error with Auth controller \Builder::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar, null given, called in /var/www/newlara/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 1899 and defined

Comment: Why did you use two tables? you could use user groups to differentiate normal users from admins.